# Can I create a DLL compatible with both standard .NET Framework and .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: .net, dll, compact-framework

I'd like certain data functionality to be shared between my .NET desktop application and .NET CF app.

Is it possible to create a universal library accessible by both versions of the application or I need to create two separate DLL's?

Comment: FWIW, my experience is that trying to maintain a single binary for both is way, way cumbersome and tedious.  Shared code, as @sblom suggests, is the only practical way to go.

Comment: related [how-to-write-a-class-library-that-will-work-on-net-3-5-compact-framework-and-re](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547278/how-to-write-a-class-library-that-will-work-on-net-3-5-compact-framework-and-re)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile a library on .NET Framework & .NET Compact Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537590/how-to-compile-a-library-on-net-framework-net-compact-framework)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes--the desktop .NET runtime knows how to load and run .NET CF DLLs, so your first step would be to build your library for the Compact Framework.

You'll find that from time to time you'll want to use features of the Desktop framework, and you can pull those in using reflection.

Here's [a very through intro to the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163387.aspx) in MSDN Magazine.

**NOTE:** If it's possible for your mobile and desktop versions to share code but not the .dll specifically, then you'll have an easier time building this and staying happy if you use conditional compilation instead.

Comment: +1 for the shared code hint. That's exactly what we do at work and it worked out very well for us, even though it's a little bit extra effort.

Comment: You can also rip the full .NET framework code from the mono source on github, and use the parts u need.